# iOS: Random black screen when loading the app

Tags: ios, tableview

I am having an issue, when I am loading my app I sometimes get a black screen, the app doesn't crash but I cannot get out of this black screen. The app is opening on a tableview loading remote data. The bug is quite random so I have no clue how to replicate it and debug it. I think it happens mostly the first time I install the app, but it also appears later on sometimes... I tried different answers here but none of them applied.
Any idea where this could come from?

[image]

Comment: Without showing any code, it will be hard to answer. If the "loading remote data" is done in the main thread, then the most likely cause is that the loading hangs. Make sure to load remote data in an asynchronous fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things I just ended up deleting the view controller in the storyboard and recreating it from scratch and the problem disappeared. I'm not sure what was the issue, maybe some bug in Xcode...

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem! Make sure to accept this answer so others can find it easier

Comment: what language is your app written in? I have a similar problem on deploying an Angular app to iOS (but only when the screen is in portrait mode). It displays the splash screen and then goes blank black. If you then rotate it to landscape mode, the black screen goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know is that you might be using an image exceeding the max supported resolution by the graphics card of the phone, which shows up as black on some devices.

please make more details on the app so we can help you.